# Find first/next position of value in array

Tags: arrays, sas

I am looking for a way in SAS so search for a value in an array similar to the `index()` or `find()` functions?

For example, to search for a value of `11` in an array called `arr`, starting from the first position in the array you would do something like this:

```
data want;
  array arr [5:7] (10,11,12);
  search_for = 11;
  pos = find_in_array(arr, search_for, 5); 
  put pos=;
run;
```

The printed value would be `6` (as the array is dimensioned from 5-7).

Comment: I don't know of one out of the box.  Is there is a reason you don't just roll your own in FCMP?

Comment: WHICHC/WHICHN but only finds the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHICHC/WHICHN
 will search an array or list of variables and return the first occurrence only.